# Insert data to a table using hibernate inside rest web service

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jersey

I have made a rest web service and i m trying to insert some values to a table using hibernate. I am getting below error.

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
        at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.<init>(DebuggingClassWriter.java:47)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:135)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:269)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:425)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1291)
        at com.dtdc.cns.CNS.getCns(CNS.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ObjectOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:258)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this com.dtdc.cns.CNS.getCns ?  Could you post the method perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises most commonly when there are multiple versions of the ASM JAR on the runtime classpath.  ASM used to be a popular library and therefore many other libraries have historically depended on it.  However, when the runtime classpath contains multiple versions of the ASM JAR, only one is version of the JAR is loaded (which one is loaded varies by platform).

You need to scan your runtime classpath and ensure that there is only version of the ASM JAR.  Be warned though, ASM is a very notorious library and although the latest version of the library should work generally, in many cases that may not work.  You will have to try different versions of ASM until you find one that works for all the libraries you are using.